# Xpath - selecting attributes based on its element name

Tags: xpath, attributes

I would like to select an **attribute** based on its parent element.

One way to do it is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="@Name[name(..) = 'EntityType' and namespace-uri(..)= 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm']">
```

Is it possible to do it in a shorter way - something similar to (whic does not work)

`@Name[../edm:EntiyType]`

Namespace prefixes are already defined in the document (I can for example select //*/edm:EntityType)

Thanks,
  Matra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how you apply your templates the following should work

```
<xsl:template match="edm:EntiyType/@Name">
```

Comment: No, this is not OK, because it select an element, EntityType instead of attribute @Name

Comment: According to http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php it should match attribute not element.

Comment: Of course. You are right - I have tested it and it works. Simple and beautiful. I was looking at the same link few minutes ago, but did not see the answer.